# How many 8 character password are there

Tags: math, passwords

How many 8 character passwords are there? 
The conditions that must hold are the followings:

- There are lowercase, uppercase and numbers in the password.
- The passwords are 8 characters, so not 7 or 9 **ONLY** 8 character passwords.

Comment: lowercase and uppercase *what* exactly? If letters, what kind of letters, ASCII? Latin-1? Or all of Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears in the other answers, you have a set of 26+26+10=62 characters (upper case letters, lower case letters, digits).

And if you have no other conditions, all of those characters can appear in all 8 positions, making the number of [permutations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) 62<sup>8</sup>, 218340105584896.

Comment: Assuming that the 'lowercase' and 'uppercase' groupings are ASCII letters, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I know what you mean. The nick would be tevemadár when written using my native alphabet.